# Change Detection in Cypress Angular Component Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, cypress-component-test-runner

I am using cypress angular component testing to try to test weather or not a button is disabled.

I am testing the following code:

```
this.subsink.sink = this.manageService.validCompetitorListener
.subscribe((validCompetitor:ValidCompetitor)=>{
  this.validCompetitor = validCompetitor;
  //this.cdref.detectChanges();
})
```

I took out the cdref.detectChanges, because when I run the e2e test, this produces an error. validCompetitorListener is an rxjs BehaviorSubject

The template code is :

```
<button
    data-cy="save-btn"
    class="btn btn-success"
    [disabled]="validCompetitor.invalid"
    (click)="save()"
  >Save</button>
```

The following Test works:

```
it.only('should save data to system', () => {
  cy.wrap(true).then(() => {
    manageService.updateAthlete(true, new Athlete(getMockAthlete()));
    manageService.updateRegister(true,{belt_id:5});
  });
  cy.get('#info').click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="save-btn"]').click();
  
});
```

BUT the only reason I use the cy.get('#info').click() statement is to get change detection to work so my component, since changeDetection caused an error when I ran the e2e test.  If this was a standard Angular unit test I would include fixture.detectChanges.  Is there an equivelent in cypress component testing?

Comment: Maybe we can fix instead the error with the E2Es, what do you think? Can you update your post with the error ?

Comment: e2e was working properly without the manual change Detection, then I wrote the Component Test, Then I added the Change detection and broke the e2e test.  Since manual Change detection is frowned upon, I decided to try and fix the Component test.  See @AliF50's answer for a good work solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do the following to get a handle on the `fixture`.

```
let myFixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

beforeEach(() => {
   cy.mount(Component)
    .then(({ fixture }) => {
        myFixture = fixture
    })
});

// should be able to do myFixture.detectChanges() now.
```